# Mongo regex to prioritize anchor at the beginning and fall back to substring match in ONE query

Tags: regex, mongodb

Assume I have a collection with the complete set of records from 'aaaa' to 'zzzz':

```
{text: 'aaaa'}
{text: 'aaab'}
...
{text: 'zzzy'}
{text: 'zzzz'}
```

I want to provide up to N autocomplete matches against it. Thus, `m` should return `maaa`, `maab` etc. *before* returning `aaam` or `aabm`. Can this be done in *one* query?

If I simply search for `{text: {$regex: 'm'}}`, whatever was stored in `$natural` order will be returned first. Sorting by `text` doesn't help. A regex anchoring the target string at the beginning, `{text: {$regex: '^m|m'}}`, doesn't help either, as `^m` fails and `.*m` will match instead. I've tried `$or`-ing the two, but still the results matching just `m` are returned first.

Here's [the same question for SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265544/how-to-prioritize-a-like-query-select-based-on-string-position-in-field).

I suspect I'll have to run first a query for `{text: {$regex: '^m'}}` and if fewer than N results are return, append results from a second query for `m` anywhere in the string, `{text: {$regex: 'm'}}`.

Is there a faster way to prioritize matches closer to the start of the string, or at least that start at `^`?

Comment: A full text search engine would be a better match. You could consider the feature coming very soon in v2.6 or something like Elastic Search. A regex isn't going to sort with weighting.