# Prioritize MySQL SELECT/LIKE result in Repository

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I want to create a query that values more precise search terms, e.g. search for "Essen" should return `Essen` currently it returns `Evessen` as this is a valid value as well.

My current function:

```
public function findCities($city){

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('z');

    $qb
        ->select('z')
        ->where($qb->expr()->like('z.city', ':city'))
        ->orderBy('z.code')
        ->setParameter('city', '%'.$city . '%');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Based on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265544/how-to-prioritize-a-like-query-select-based-on-string-position-in-field) advice I created a repository function:

```
public function findCities($city){

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('z');

    $qb
        ->select('z')
        ->where($qb->expr()->like('z.city', ':city'))
        ->orderBy('INSTR(z.city, '.$city.'), z.city')
        ->setParameter('city', '%'.$city . '%');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Unfortunately it returns `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 70: Error: Expected known function, got 'INSTR'`

Any other approach (that does NOT return an array, as there is a function that needs heavy altering if the output is an array, I'd like to avoid that) maybe?

Comment: DQL only supports a limited number of sql functions: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions.  instr is not one of them.  You will have to add your own user defined function or use one of dql bundles out there. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html Or, as @DenisAlimox has suggested, use a native query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no INSTR function in DQL, that's why you get this error [see docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#functions-operators-aggregates)

instead you can make NativeQuery [see docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

something like this

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();

$rsm->addEntityResult('City', 'c');

// for every selected field you should do this
$rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'name', 'name');

$em = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createNativeQuery('
        SELECT
          id, name
        FROM cities WHERE city LIKE '%:city%'
ORDER BY INSTR(city, ':city'), city',
        $rsm
    )->setParameter('city', $city);

return $em->getResult();
```

Comment: This works almost perfect, but  `$rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'price', 'price');` is a foreign key, where I need the values from, unfortunately it is `null`. How do I get those as well?

Comment: @PrimuS see the docs please `<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder;

$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.name, a.id AS address_id, a.street, a.city " .
       "FROM users u INNER JOIN address a ON u.address_id = a.id";

$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($entityManager);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('MyProject\User', 'u');
$rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('MyProject\Address', 'a', 'u', 'address', array('id' => 'address_id'));`